# How to create a Output Processor (Scrapy framework) that composes the output of several functions without get "None" on the final output?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I have this code:

items.py

```
class MyItem(Item):

    never_populated_field = Field()
    just_punctuation = Field()
    unwanted_text = Field()
    some_other_text = Field()
```

loaders.py

```
def eliminate_string_without_text(txt):
    if re.search(r'\w+', txt, flags=re.UNICODE) :
        return txt
    else:
        return None

def eliminate_unwanted_text(txt):
    if txt == 'Remove this text!' :
        return None
    else:
        return txt

class MyLoader(ItemLoader):

    default_input_processor = MapCompose(
                                    lambda x: u' '.join(x.split()),
                                    unicode.lower,
                                    eliminate_string_without_text,
                                    eliminate_unwanted_text)
    default_output_processor = Join()
```

And it is working correctly.

input: (The inputs are taken from a html document, with selectors.)

```
i = MyLoader(item=MyItem())
i.add_value('just_punctuation', [u'.?!', u' \n.'])
i.add_value('unwanted_text', [u'Remove  this \n text!'])
i.add_value('some_other_text', [u'let   me', u'on   output...'])
```

output:

```
{'some_other_text': u'let me on output...'}
```

Now my problem...
Suppose this input:

```
i = MyLoader(item=MyItem())
i.add_value('just_punctuation', [u'.?!', u' \n.'])
i.add_value('unwanted_text', [u'Remove  this \n'])
i.add_value('unwanted_text', [u' text', u'!'])
i.add_value('some_other_text', [u'let   me', u'on'])
i.add_value('some_other_text', [u'  output', u'...'])
```

I want the same output as above. But instead the output is:

```
{'some_other_text': u'let me on output',
 'unwanted_text': u'Remove this text'}
```

It is right. The function "eliminate_string_without_text" eliminates the "..." of the "some_other_text" and also the function "eliminate_unwanted_text" will never eliminate anything because the input is divided in several parts.
So, I need to put both "eliminate" functions on the Output Processor, after the Join(). I have tried several things and I still think that this should work:

```
default_input_processor = MapCompose(
                                lambda x: u' '.join(x.split()),
                                unicode.lower)
default_output_processor = Compose(
                                Join(),
                                eliminate_string_without_text,
                                eliminate_unwanted_text)
```

And, in fact, it works:

```
{'just_punctuation': None,
 'never_populated_field': None,
 'some_other_text': u'let me on output...',
 'unwanted_text': None}
```

Finally, how to do that without getting "None" on the output? (I want the first output example I gave.) I could make the both "eliminate" functions as Item Pipeline, but I would not like to. I have tried to change them to receive a list instead of a string. I have read the scrapy implementation of the Loader too, but I am new to python and I could not understand how all the things work.
Actually, I even don't understand why there is no "None" on output when I use just the Join()?

Thanks!

(And a side-effect question... When there are more than one "add_value" for the same field, are the values processed in the same order that they were added?)

**Update:** My code have changed a lot before I could try the suggestion of @user1147688. Anyway, I think this behavior was changed on Scrapy 0.24.0, according to https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/556.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert your empty list, which is printed as "None" to an empty string. Try using `str()`.